# Dygraph troubleshoot CSV

Tags: javascript, csv, dygraphs

This is straight from [dygraphs](http://dygraphs.com/) under the **Error Bars** section and I have the csv file in the same dir as the html with the dygraph code.  Neither Firefox or Chrome throw an error or draw any lines.  It only displays the axis and background grid.  How do I go about chasing this down?
Is the .csv file getting loaded ? Where should I start looking, in dygraph-combined.js?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dygraph-combined.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="graphdiv4" style="width:480px; height:320px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  g4 = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("graphdiv4"),
    "twonormals.csv",
    {
      rollPeriod: 7,
      showRoller: true,
      errorBars: true,
      valueRange: [50,125]
    }
  );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It was the twonormals.csv file from dygraphs that was messed up.  I tried the temperatures.csv file they had and that worked fine.  Any one want to answer this one, it's free :)

Comment: Actually a better answer would be what is up with the data file to cause this lack of response? http://dygraphs.com/twonormals.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that twonormals.csv is world-readable. Can you view/download it by typing its URL directly in the URL bar?

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and the server browser downloaded the file.